# Secure dishwasher hoses under countertop with zip ties

Tags: carpentry, coaxial-cable

Good Afternoon,

I need to tie the dishwasher hoses to the countertop underneath

I have decided to tie them with zip-ties in the event that I have to remove the dishwasher to access the plumbing (*I just have to cut the zip ties, instead of unscrewing permanent brackets*).

I am **thinking of  using cable staples (*image below*)  and inserting them underneath the countertop, and just looping the zip ties in them.

**I am wondering  if anyone has any other better suggestions?**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh btw the countertop is 3/4 of an inch

Comment: What is the composition of the countertop? If it is particleboard and you try to drive that staple into it... it may pull right out.

Answer (score 4):

Use ring-ended zip-ties and screw them in place. That's what the rings are for

Why complicate it?

Answer (score 3):

Pounding those staples up under the counter top might jar it lose or crack some caulking. I'd think about using some eye screws which would go up there easier.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Bend radius and pipe damage

First of all, the edges of zip ties can dig into the pipe. Consider using something to pad around the pipe, maybe a bit of rag or something like that.

And you also need to consider the bend radius on the pipe. If it's too tight, the pipe will collapse. Make sure you're not trying to do what the pipe won't do.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to connect a zip tie to a flat surface, and I don't want to risk cracking the far side of that surface due to drilling it and inserting a threaded fastener, I use a surface-mount fastener designed specifically for zip ties to connect onto.  Web-search **"adhesive zip-tie mount"**.  The adhesive foam tape on some of these will stay attached to nonporous / smooth surfaces forever.  But if I had a surface which I was concerned adhesive foam tape might not adhere to adequately, I would just drill some small (1/8") holes around the perimeter of the mount and use either 5-minute epoxy or RTV/silicone sealant (making sure some squished through the holes) to attach the mount.  (Be aware of the material the mount is made from and make sure any custom glue/adhesive you use is compatible with it.  Whenever I'm in doubt and I'm epoxying, I use 80-grit sandpaper liberally.)